# credential file moved after compile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot app (1.3.6) and in the `resources` folder, I have this file `credentials.json`

At some point, I load this file like this

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                  .setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/credentials.json"))
```

it works fine in development, but when I package the app (`mvn clean package`) the file isn't located at `src/main/resources` anymore, it is moved to the root of the project (I unzipped the .jar)

then I tried to put this file on the root of project and changed to `FileInputStream("credentials.json"))` and got almost the same result: works fine in dev, but when I package, this file actually disappears.
I know that I may be missing something here, but I have no idea what

Comment: You probably want to use `getResourceAsStream(...)` from the classloader used to load the project classes. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future:

I added

```
@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
```

and loaded the file with

```
resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:credentials.json").getInputStream()
```

the file was still at `src/main/resources`